# How can I access a nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, nested, find

I have a **collection** called **bills** in a database.

Each document in the collection is a bill that was passed in **congress**.

Within each document, there is an array called **votingRecord**, comprised of objects that are the voting records of each congress member.

**I need to be able to sort and find specific keys/values within the `votingRecord array`**, and I can't figure it out.

I tried examples listed here, but my issue is that each document in my collection has the **nested array of objects** made of the representatives ("votingRecord").

I need to set an initial filter in my query so that I can search the specific votingRecord for the specific bill.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc209b7af26e560a3204bcc"),
    "bill_id" : "hr676-116",
    "title" : "To reiterate the support of the Congress of the United States for the North Atlantic Treaty Organization, and for other purposes.",
    "sponsorState" : "CA",
    "sponsorParty" : "D",
    "summary" : "NATO Support Act  This bill prohibits the appropriation or use of funds to withdraw the United States from the North Atlantic Treaty Organization.",
    "primarySubject" : "NATO Support Act  This bill prohibits the appropriation or use of funds to withdraw the United States from the North Atlantic Treaty Organization.",
    "introducedDate" : "2019-01-17",
    "latestMAction" : "Received in the Senate.",
    "votingRecord" : [ 
        {
            "person" : 400440,
            "state" : "AK",
            "district" : 0,
            "vote" : "Yea",
            "name" : "Rep. Don Young [R]",
            "party" : "Republican"
        },

       //( five hundred or so of these objects(all reps + senators), ending with)

],
    "latestMActionDate" : "2019-01-23",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

my MongoDB shell isn't responding to any of the queries I've made.

```
db.bills.find({"introducedDate": 2019-01-03},{votingRecord: {$elemMatch: {state:"FL"}}})
```

the above query felt like the closest, because I specified by "introducedDate," but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **filter out the irrelevant** entries from votingRecord array, then you can use the query like:

```
db.bills.find({"introducedDate": "2019-01-17", "votingRecord.state": "FL"},
{
   "votingRecord.$": 1,     //using $ will only project matched objects   
   //..other fileds that you want to project

});
```

**provided**, you want the bill on 2019-01-17 date, with the voting record from "FL" state.

***But***, lets say

you want the bill on 2019-01-03 date, with the voting record from "FL" state and district "0".

using the above query with an additional condition for the `district` will not help,

as it won't get that, we want the **state** to be "FL" and **district** to be 0 in the **same object of the vottingRecord**, it will act like an **OR** condition here,

**to use it as AND, you need to use $elemMatch operator**,

like this.

```
db.bills.find({"introducedDate": "2019-01-03", "votingRecord": {$elemMatch: {state:"FL", district: 0}}},
{
   "votingRecord.$": 1,     //using $ will only project matched objects   
   //..other fileds that you want to project

});
```

Comment: AH ok.  Getting closer thank you. I just need to see all the votes by certain states, and I am too green at this to not break apart your answer and only return that. I tried deleting the additional "{"votingRecord.$:1,"}" and it's not giving it back to me. But you've nudged me further so thank you.